# getDisplayMedia (get the list of available options)

Tags: screensharing, get-display-media

I'm trying to get the list of available stream sources which are shown on native chrome pickup screen, when calling getDisplayMedia.
[image]

Is there an callback which returns an array of available options, I want to customize this native pickup screen?
Thank you in advance